# how to splite a column value in multipale column

Tags: sql-server

can you tell me 
how to dived

```
ID     SN    Types
1      123   ABC,XYZ,TEST, RJK,CDF,TTT,UMB,UVX
2      234   RJK,CDF,TTT,UMB,UVX,TTT,UMB,UVX
3      345   OID,XYZ,TTT,UMB,UVX,TTT,UMB,UVX
```

as

```
 ID     SN    Types1  Types2  Types3  Types4  Types5  Types6  Types7  Types8
 1      123   ABC       XYZ    TEST     RJK    CDF     TTT     UMB     UVX  
 2      234   RJK       CDF    TTT      UMB    UVX     TTT     UMB     UVX 
 3      345   OID       XYZ    TTT      UMB    UVX     TTT     UMB     UVX
```

please send me sql code 
thanx,

Comment: Have you tried coding yourself? SO is not a code writing service. Look up CHARINDEX() and PATINDEX() functions, make an effort and then come back if you get stuck somewhere, we will then be glad to help

Comment: As long as some of us keep writing code for the benefit of people showing zero research effort, my above comment is meaningless

Comment: @Raj yet you didn't even vote to close? How else do you expect to prevent others from enjoying solving a query problem, regardless of whether the OP did enough prior research to satisfy you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, create a split function that maintains order:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[SplitStrings_Ordered]
(
    @List       NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @Delimiter  NVARCHAR(255)
)
RETURNS TABLE
AS
    RETURN (SELECT [Index] = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Number), Item 
    FROM (SELECT Number, Item = SUBSTRING(@List, Number, 
      CHARINDEX(@Delimiter, @List + @Delimiter, Number) - Number)
     FROM (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [object_id])
      FROM sys.all_objects) AS n(Number)
      WHERE Number <= CONVERT(INT, LEN(@List))
      AND SUBSTRING(@Delimiter + @List, Number, LEN(@Delimiter)) = @Delimiter
    ) AS y);
```

Now, you can use this function in combination with a `PIVOT`. This is a self-enclosed example but you can just replace `@d` in the last query with whatever your real table is.

```
DECLARE @d TABLE(ID INT, SN INT, Types NVARCHAR(MAX));

INSERT @d VALUES
(1,123,N'ABC,XYZ,TEST, RJK,CDF,TTT,UMB,UVX'),
(2,234,N'RJK,CDF,TTT,UMB,UVX,TTT,UMB,UVX'  ),
(3,345,N'OID,XYZ,TTT,UMB,UVX,TTT,UMB,UVX'  );

SELECT ID,SN,
 Types1 = [1], Types2 = [2], Types3 = [3], Types4 = [4],
 Types1 = [5], Types6 = [6], Types7 = [7], Types8 = [8]
FROM @d AS d CROSS APPLY dbo.SplitStrings_Ordered(d.Types, ',') AS y
PIVOT (MAX(Item) FOR [Index] IN ([1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[6],[7],[8])) AS p;
```

Answer (score 0):

T-SQL is not well suited for dealing with comma-separated values.  However with creative use of a [Recursive CTE](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186243%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), it is possible to split up the columns without too much effort.  The following query makes the assumption that there is never more than 8 types total in a row in the original data - it can be trivially extended to handle any number of types (albeit not dynamic, the maximum number must be known):

```
;with TypesSplit as (

    select [ID], [SN], 1 as [Index],
    case when CHARINDEX(',', [Types]) <> 0 then substring([Types], CHARINDEX(',', [Types])+1, 1000) else '' end as [Types],
    case when CHARINDEX(',', [Types]) <> 0 then substring([Types], 1, CHARINDEX(',', [Types])-1) else [Types] end as [Type]
    from Types

    union all

    select [ID], [SN], [Index] + 1 as [Index],
    case when CHARINDEX(',', [Types]) <> 0 then substring([Types], CHARINDEX(',', [Types])+1, 1000) else '' end as [Types],
    case when CHARINDEX(',', [Types]) <> 0 then substring([Types], 1, CHARINDEX(',', [Types])-1) else [Types] end as [Type]
    from TypesSplit
    where LEN([Types])>0

)
select [ID],[SN],
    max(case when [Index]=1 then [Type] end) as Types1,
    max(case when [Index]=2 then [Type] end) as Types2,
    max(case when [Index]=3 then [Type] end) as Types3,
    max(case when [Index]=4 then [Type] end) as Types4,
    max(case when [Index]=5 then [Type] end) as Types5,
    max(case when [Index]=6 then [Type] end) as Types6,
    max(case when [Index]=7 then [Type] end) as Types7,
    max(case when [Index]=8 then [Type] end) as Types8
from TypesSplit
group by [ID],[SN]
```

(Demo: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/c522f/9)

The basic idea is to use [CHARINDEX](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186323.aspx) to find the locations of each comma, then [SUBSTRING](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187748.aspx) to split out each type from the beginning.  The recursion loops through all of the types until there are none left to consume.  The types are numbered via the `[Index]` column to allow reproducing them in the same order in the output.  The output is basically a pivot table of the row data generated by the recursive CTE, which looks like this before pivoting:

```
| ID |  SN | INDEX |                        TYPES | TYPE |
|----|-----|-------|------------------------------|------|
|  1 | 123 |     1 | XYZ,TEST,RJK,CDF,TTT,UMB,UVX |  ABC |
|  2 | 234 |     1 |  CDF,TTT,UMB,UVX,TTT,UMB,UVX |  RJK |
|  3 | 345 |     1 |  XYZ,TTT,UMB,UVX,TTT,UMB,UVX |  OID |
|  3 | 345 |     2 |      TTT,UMB,UVX,TTT,UMB,UVX |  XYZ |
|  3 | 345 |     3 |          UMB,UVX,TTT,UMB,UVX |  TTT |
|  3 | 345 |     4 |              UVX,TTT,UMB,UVX |  UMB |
|  3 | 345 |     5 |                  TTT,UMB,UVX |  UVX |
|  3 | 345 |     6 |                      UMB,UVX |  TTT |
|  3 | 345 |     7 |                          UVX |  UMB |
|  3 | 345 |     8 |                              |  UVX |
|  2 | 234 |     2 |      TTT,UMB,UVX,TTT,UMB,UVX |  CDF |
|  2 | 234 |     3 |          UMB,UVX,TTT,UMB,UVX |  TTT |
|  2 | 234 |     4 |              UVX,TTT,UMB,UVX |  UMB |
|  2 | 234 |     5 |                  TTT,UMB,UVX |  UVX |
|  2 | 234 |     6 |                      UMB,UVX |  TTT |
|  2 | 234 |     7 |                          UVX |  UMB |
|  2 | 234 |     8 |                              |  UVX |
|  1 | 123 |     2 |     TEST,RJK,CDF,TTT,UMB,UVX |  XYZ |
|  1 | 123 |     3 |          RJK,CDF,TTT,UMB,UVX | TEST |
|  1 | 123 |     4 |              CDF,TTT,UMB,UVX |  RJK |
|  1 | 123 |     5 |                  TTT,UMB,UVX |  CDF |
|  1 | 123 |     6 |                      UMB,UVX |  TTT |
|  1 | 123 |     7 |                          UVX |  UMB |
|  1 | 123 |     8 |                              |  UVX |
```

After pivoting, the final output looks like this:

```
| ID |  SN | TYPES1 | TYPES2 | TYPES3 | TYPES4 | TYPES5 | TYPES6 | TYPES7 | TYPES8 |
|----|-----|--------|--------|--------|--------|--------|--------|--------|--------|
|  1 | 123 |    ABC |    XYZ |   TEST |    RJK |    CDF |    TTT |    UMB |    UVX |
|  2 | 234 |    RJK |    CDF |    TTT |    UMB |    UVX |    TTT |    UMB |    UVX |
|  3 | 345 |    OID |    XYZ |    TTT |    UMB |    UVX |    TTT |    UMB |    UVX |
```

Comment: sorry but i have not used this format it is not suite for me..

Comment: @gourishankar: The output is showing an intermediate step to help explain what the recursive CTE is doing.  The actual output of the query is the same as you desired in your question, as you can see by viewing the linked demo. I updated the post for clarity with an example of the final output.

Comment: @gourishankar you need to learn from what people are showing you here. It is not a code delivery service, but a way for people to teach you how to solve problems. You can't just say "this format is not suitable"...

Comment: @Aaron Bertrand sir i am already make this type function for my purpose but my issue is not this then i say it....thanx